# Fire function on order creation to remove coupons from parent subscription

Tags: php, methods, woocommerce, coupon, woocommerce-subscriptions

I have the following function, I want it fire every time an order for a subscription is created.

I then want it to remove the store credit coupons from the parent subscription (as renewal orders will contain the coupon).

I'm getting the error:

> *"PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method WC_Order_Item_Coupon::get_discount_type()"*.

Where am I going wrong?

Is it passing in the parent subscription item in the right way?

```
   function remove_store_credit($subscription) {
    
      $coupons = $subscription->get_items( 'coupon' );
      foreach ( $coupons as $coupon ) {
        if($coupon->get_discount_type() == "smart_coupon"){
          $subscription->remove_coupon( $coupon->get_code() );
        }
      }
    
    }
    add_action('woocommerce_subscription_payment_complete','remove_store_credit',10,1);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method `get_discount_type()` belongs to `WC_Coupon` Class but not to `WC_Order_Item_Coupon` Class.

So try you need to get an instance object of the `WC_Coupon` inside the coupon items foreach loop.

```
function remove_store_credit( $subscription ) {
    // Loop through order coupon items
    foreach ( $subscription->get_items( 'coupon' ) as $item ) {
        $coupon = new WC_Coupon( $item->get_code() ); // get an instance of the WC_Coupon Object 

        if( $coupon->get_discount_type() == "smart_coupon" ){
            $subscription->remove_coupon( $item->get_code() );
        }
    }
}
add_action('woocommerce_subscription_payment_complete', 'remove_store_credit', 10, 1);
```

It should solve this error.

Comment: Ah of course! Thanks for pointing it out, that works now

Comment: Is there a way to set the coupon usage to 1? I've put this in the if statement but it doesn't seem to change the usage `update_post_meta( $coupon->get_id(), 'usage_count', '1' );`

Comment: @Rob one by user or one at all?

Comment: One at all, they're tied to a specific user by email address anyways so it just needs to change to 1 after use. It has 1 already set on the limit but when the order is going through it's not counting against a use, set if I can set that as a fallback.

Comment: Better try to use from `$coupon` variable *(the WC_Coupon Object instance)*:  `$coupon->decrease_usage_count();` and `$coupon->save();`

Comment: I tried that one but misunderstood it's use... that worked, thanks again